# No available Texlive 2018 windows installer?

Tags: texlive, installing

Has anyone installed Texlive 2018 on windows? I follow the [official link](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) to download the windows installer. But it in fact shows pictures with 2017 and is interupted by an error due to some mismatch between 2017 and 2018. How should I proceed?

Comment: I installed it on Windows 10 yesterday, from here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html, clicking on install-tl-windows.exe.

Comment: The mismatch is probably your mirror that is not yet up to date. My normal mirror was out of date on Monday and installation gave a similar error. Mirror was up to date, Tuesday...  You can check the mirror by visiting it in a browser, under the `texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/`, the dates there should be at least 30 April. Otherwise use a different mirror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for another day and try again. TeXlive is distributed by a system of mirror servers and after publishing TeXlive 2018 it takes some days to sync all the mirror servers. You simply might have hit a not fully synced server.